# nginx fresh install configuration

Tags: nginx

I've just installed nginx on my server; now I can see with

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

that it is in execution with my user (is this correct or should it run with root?);
anyway I'm not able to do anything with it, cannot stop it for example since

```
nginx -s stop
```

outputs:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() 
"/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2017/05/02 04:03:34 [warn] 2482#2482: the "user" directive makes sense 
only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in 
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
2017/05/02 04:03:34 [notice] 2482#2482: signal process started
2017/05/02 04:03:34 [error] 2482#2482: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" 
failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I've googling around about these warnings and errors, but I can't really understand them; can someone please explain:

- the meaning of the log file warning and the .pid file error
- if nginx should run with my user or with root (or something else)

**UPDATE:**

I'm using ubuntu server 16.04 (xenial) and I've installed nginx adding

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
```

to sources.list and then

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

**UPDATE 2**

Trying to stop nginx with "sudo" still leads to error:

```
nginx: [error] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

anyway I am also confused about why

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

shows the process running under my user (but it is not possible to kill it using the PID, and every time I run the command the PID is different)

**UPDATE 3**

running

```
nginx -t
```

outputs:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() 
"/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2017/05/02 15:32:53 [warn] 8535#8535: the "user" directive makes sense 
only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in 
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2017/05/02 15:32:53 [emerg] 8535#8535: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" 
failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: What distribution are you using (debian, ubuntu, redhat...)?

Comment: I've updated the question with these details, thanks

Comment: Please run "ps -ef | grep nginx" and add the output to your question. IMHO this is likely a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have root privileges when you want to start or stop the nginx daemon. Running the commands as normal user won't work.

This is pretty much standard for all daemons in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

How do you have installed nginx ? 
Maybe you should try to use repository package for having good default configuration otherwise you can read the nginx manual to get more information.
For me your problem is just mis-configured server.
Can you specify the distribution you are using ? `cat /etc/issue`

Comment: I've updated the question with the installation details; /etc/issue contains:

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS \n \l

Comment: How do you have installed Nginx ?

Comment: It is written in the question's update: by adding `http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ xenial nginx` to sources.list and then running `sudo apt-get install nginx`

Comment: have you run ``apt update`` before ? 
You should control nginx with ``service [nginx start|stop|reload]``
You can test your configuration with ``nginx -t`` 
Note : all of these command need to bee run with sudo

Comment: Yes I've done an update before installing; I've added the output of `nginx -t` in the update 3 section of the question

Comment: Could you try with sudo ?

Comment: yes running it with sudo it outputs `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful` so I guess that's fine; I have to say that I've formatted the server and re-installed ubuntu-server 16.04; before my home folder was encrypted and that was causing some issues with my ssh connection without password; I don't know if that can have any kind of influence on nginx too

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the Nginx main process as root. You can then configure Nginx to run the worker processes as the user or group you like - this is what the error messages refer to.

Exactly how you do this depends on your operating system, which you haven't specified. Now you know what the problem is you can use Google to work out the details.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx runs as a daemon and should be managed as a service rather than as a user process. Under ubuntu, you can use the `service` command:

- `sudo service nginx start` starts nginx
- `sudo service nginx stop` stops nginx
- `sudo service nginx restart` stops then restarts nginx
- `sudo service nginx reload` tells nginx to reload its configuration files without stopping the service

EDIT: and to get status, `sudo service nginx status`.